# Get data from dynamically added element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function thats create a element dynamically:

```js
  $('#bookUserSeat').on('click', function(){
    $('#seatBookings').append('<div class="alert alert-info"><a class="deleteSeat" data-seatNumber="' + $(this).data('seatNumber')  + '"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>');
    $('#modalBookSeat').modal('hide');
  });
```

Now I have a function that works on the on click event:

```js
  $('#seatBookings').on('click', 'a.deleteSeat', function(){
    var seat = $(this).data('seatNumber');
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
```

But the var seat is empty. How can I get the data attr from the dynamically created link?

Comment: I have multiple links inside div#seatBookings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-data` and `data()` are case-sensitive.

However, the attribute gets converted to lower-case when you use `.append()`, so you actually have `data-seatnumber` and `data("seatNumber")` which don't match.

Demo:

```js
$("#mydiv").append('<div data-lowercase="lowercase" data-mixedCase="mixedCase">inner</div>');

console.log("lowerCase", $("#mydiv>div").data("lowerCase"));
console.log("lowercase", $("#mydiv>div").data("lowercase"));
console.log("mixedCase", $("#mydiv>div").data("mixedCase")); 
console.log("mixedcase", $("#mydiv>div").data("mixedcase"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

As you can see, the `data-` is added with `mixedCase` but gives `undefined` on `.data("mixedCase")` - but works fine with `.data("mixedcase")` (all lower).

Always use all-lower attributes for compatibility.