# Capital letters in html attributs

Tags: html, jquery, css, d3.js, jquery-animate

I want to add animation on my chart.I'm using jquery(append) to add animation tag on my html page but the animation doesn't work.
The animation tag attributs such as attributename or repeatcount have one capital letter and if i add this with attr method or another  the capital letter is ignored and the animation doesn't work.

```
<rect fill="#555" width="2" height="2" x="0" y="0">  
  <animate attributename="x" from="0" to="0" attributename="XML" dur="1.5s" repeatcount="indefinite"></animate>
  <animate attributename="y" from="0" to="0" attributetype="XML" dur="1.5s" repeatcount="indefinite"></animate>
</rect>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from dynamically added element on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244535/get-data-from-dynamically-added-element-on-click)

Comment: Picking out some points from your question:  1-capital (mixed case) and `jquery.append()` - attributes are case-sensitive, but jquery.append converts your html attributes to lower case.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244784/2181514 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're moving from 0 to 0. If you try to put the capital letters and tell the box to move (let's say from 0 to 2) you'll see something :)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <rect fill="#555" width="2" height="2" x="0" y="0">
    <animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="2" attributeName="XML" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    <animate attributeName="y" from="0" to="2" attributeType="XML" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is just an example my problems is attributs name i cannot add attribut name with capital letter.Do you have solution for this ?